# Erro quando uma imagem é carregada em uma segunda janela tkinter - Python

Tags: python, imagem, tkinter

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um pequeno programa usando `tkinter`, onde, na primeira janela há um botão que abre uma segunda janela onde há uma imagem. Entretanto, o programa não carrega essa imagem, dizendo que ela não existe. Caso eu execute o segundo programa sozinho, onde há somente a imagem, tudo ocorre bem, o problema é quando ele é aberto por um outro programa.

**Programa 'teste'**

```
from tkinter import *

def abrir():
  exec(open('teste2.py').read())

app = Tk()
app.geometry('100x100')
but = Button(app, text='abrir', command=abrir)
but.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

**Programa 'teste2'**

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()
app.geometry('100x100')
img = PhotoImage(file='img/voltar.png')
lbImagem = Label(app, image=img)
lbImagem.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

**Mensagem de Erro**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/saulo/PycharmProjects/testes/Construcao/teste.py", line 4, in abrir
    exec(open('teste2.py').read())
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3143, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2567, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Erro esta no programa 'teste2', quando voce declara o img com PhotoImage, você não esta dando como parametro o master, que é onde a imagem vai ser colocada. Como você não esta declarando, ele interpreta que não há imagem para ser mostrada.

Outro erro que é possivel notar, é que PhotoImage não suporta imagens .jpg. É aceito apenas PGM, PPM, GIF e PNG.

Você pode corrigir isso apenas colocando um master e mudando seu arquivo para um dos formatos aceitos:

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()
app.geometry('100x100')

# AQUI ESTA O ERRO CORRIGIDO
img = PhotoImage(master=app, file='./img/WAZUP.gif')

lbImagem = Label(app, image=img)
lbImagem.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente aqui. OBS: No código eu não usei imagem '.jpg'.

Comment: Ah legal, perdao acho que troquei o formato quando fui fazer o teste no meu pc.